# Собственный конструктор пользовательских компонентов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Всем привет!

Можно ли как-нибудь самостоятельно написать свой конструктор пользовательских компонентов? Я заметил что в некоторых фреймворках для Visual Studio существуют собственные конструкторы пользовательских компонентов (DevExpress к примеру).

Где можно прочесть о создании собственных конструкторов? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел книгу в которой есть сведенья о дизайнере компонентов, сервисах и о разработке компонентов в целом, которые могут пригодиться в разработке.

1) [C#. Разработка компонентов в MS Visual Studio 2005/2008 (Павел Агуров)](https://books.google.by/books?id=WRXiAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA2&ots=katzWpMEvn&dq=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%20C%23%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20MS%20Visual%20Studio%202005%2F2008&hl=ru&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Так-же полезную информацию удалось найти в архиве MSDN:

2) [Writing Custom Designers for .NET Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973820.aspx)

3) [Разработка собственного дизайнера форм для .NET-приложений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335950.aspx)

Если кто-то находил или найдёт ещё информацию по дизайнерам, то буду очень благодарен если вы дополните ответ!

Comment: В журнале [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues) за декабрь 2004 года (качать chm) смотрите статью Tailor Your Application by Building a Custom Forms Designer with .NET.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ок, прочту, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov слушай, а с чего лучше начать изучение дизайнеров? В книге 1 очень клёвое изложение, но мало написано про дизайнеры. В статьях 2/3 всё очень сжато и сухо, не могу усвоить. Возможно можешь подсказать ещё источники информации по этому вопросу?

Comment: Увы, больше ничем не могу помочь. Так-то я бы Агурова предложил, не будь он уже в списке.